# Is there a way to pass a param to a function called on jQuery .click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know you can invoke a function on click by:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function);
// Assume 'function' is an actual function declared elsewhere.
```

But is there a way to pass a param into the function using that style? I know you can do:

```
$(".foo").on("click", {namespace: this}, function (e) {
    var that = e.data.namespace;

    that.function(that);
});
```

But this is not how I want to write it. I want to call an already created function on a .click event and pass params to it using the one-line notation of the top example. How do I do this?

Comment: You could use `$.proxy` if all you want to do is change the `this` reference inside the function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides you can also use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function namedFunction(yourArgument, e) {
    console.log(yourArgument);
}

$(".foo").on("click", namedFunction.bind(this, yourArgument));
```

This method was added to ECMA-262, 5th edition and might have [compatibility problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) with old browsers. You may check **MDN** for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you can't do what you're asking exactly, but you can come pretty close just by calling the function inside of the callback function:

```
$(".foo").on('click', function () { namedFunction.call(this, yourArguments); });
```

You can use `.apply` instead of `.call` if it suits you.

Comment: Bah! This is what I thought :( Thank you.

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to do it, but watch out because the "yourArguments" variable is not protected using any kind of enclosure - and since the annonymous function is called asynchronously (i.e. when you click the .foo element) - so if you have reused this variable at all, it might do what you expect.